# Google login with mechanize on ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize, google-signin

I'm trying to get to [google play developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) using ruby. But first I have to login. I'm trying like this:

```
def try_post(url, body = {}, headers = {})
  unless @agent #This just creates a new mechanize instance
    setup
  end

  puts 'Logging in'

  # Hardcoded for testing purposes
  @agent.get 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=androiddeveloper&passive=1209600&continue=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/%23&followup=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#identifier'

  form = @agent.page.forms.find {|f| f.form_node['id'] == "gaia_loginform"}

  unless form
    raise 'No login form'
  end

  form.field_with(:id => "Email").value = @config.email

  form.click_button
  form = @agent.page.forms.find {|f| f.form_node['id'] == "gaia_loginform"}

  unless form
    raise 'No login form'
  end

  form.field_with(:name => "Passwd").value = @config.password

  form.click_button

  if @agent.page.uri.host != "play.google.com"
    STDERR.puts "login failed? : uri = " + @agent.page.uri.to_s
    raise 'Google login failed'
  end

  # @agent.post(url, body)
end
```

However this fails spectacularly. I tried a few other ways (trying to populate `Passwd-hidden`, finding field by `id` and so on) but no luck. I think that the password does not get entered since when I try to `puts @agent.page.body` after the final `click_button` I see enter password text somewhere in HTML.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been digging around a bit more and found out that it's not that simple and I could not login with mechanize in any way.

So I ended up with using [watir](https://watir.com) which was fairly simple and straightforward. Here's an example:

```
browser.goto LOGIN_URL

browser.text_field(:id, 'Email').set @config.email
browser.button(:id, 'next').click

browser.text_field(:id, 'Passwd').wait_until_present
browser.text_field(:id, 'Passwd').set @config.password
browser.button(:id, 'signIn').click

# Here I wait until an element on my target page is visible and then continue
browser.link(:href, '#SOMETHING').wait_until_present
```

Hope it helps.